# Can I use "." in POST parameter names, generated by Flash?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash

I'm trying to find out if a Flash application can create a POST request, where some of the names of the posted items include the "." character?

The background:

I’m working with someone who is writing a Flash application that has to POST data to the server.  I'm working on the web application which receives and saves the data.  As such, I know little about the inner workings of Flash myself.

To allow automated data-binding at the server (within Microsoft MVC), I want the names of the POST items to use a particular naming convention.  So if I want to receive the results of two tests, I would like the POST items to use the names:

```
Tests[0].Score
Tests[0].Passed

Tests[1].Score
Tests[1].Passed
```

If this data was being submitted from a plain-old HTML form, this would be something like:

```
<input id="Areas_0__Score" name="Tests[0].Score" type="text" value="70" />
<input id="Areas_0__Passed" name="Tests[0].Passed" type="text" value="true" />
```

However, the developer says that when constructing a POST request within Flash, any items with a “.” in the name are ignored, and not included in the POST request.

Is this a known limitation of Flash, or should it be possible to include a “.” in the POST item names, as I would like?

Thanks for in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AS3 URLVariables object used to create the post variables is a object. With falsh's syntax, something like foo.bar would mean bar is a descendent/child/property of the foo object. URLVariables are, ultimately, objects also, thus something like Tests[0].Score is not the a valid name for an object. See this example: [URLVariables examples](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Especially:

```
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.exampleSessionId = new Date().getTime();
```

Makeing a variable like you suggest would not work because of this dot syntax used for object properties/descendants:

`variables.Tests[0].Score` would, to Flash, mean something like: The `variables` object has a property called `Test[0]`, which has a property called `Score` - which makes no sense/is faulty actionscript. As Flash converts the URLVariables object with its attributes into the actual HTTP post, it fails when the attributes have attributes.

Comment: Many thanks for the clear answer Kontur.  Just to be sure - is there no way to specify the POST-item's name, independently of the variable that contains the value to be posted?  I'm thinking some sort of dictionary {"Any.name.with.dots" = VariableContainingValue} where the name of the POST item is independent of the name of the variable that will provide its value?

Comment: The Flash developer found a way to do this after all.  Sorry but he hasn't relayed what he did to me, so I can't post it here for future reference.

Comment: Okay, certainly got my interest though how he did it. The answer I gave was based on what I'd assumed be the reason it is not possible. Maybe when not using URLVariables, but just encoding the variables as string like `Test[0].Score=value&Test[0].Foobar=value` might something that could be tried :) Maybe that was how he got it to work.